# how to create/alter a mysql table on multiple customer databases

Tags: mysql, database, database-migration

We have a dozen customers who each have their own database (they are all on the same RDS instance). The database schema is exactly the same for all customers.

When a new code deployment feature requires a new database table, is there a 'best practice' for creating this table on all customer databases?

We currently use a custom script that iterates over all databases and runs the 'create table xxxx' statement.

Was wondering if this is a common technique that is used, or if there's a better/safer way.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use your approach. Sometimes I create a SQL file with the create table for each database. According to me, this is a good method. The `CREATE` statement is safe because it doesn't remove or change anything so your approach is safe respect to the data.